# Creating namespace in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Am having a problem in creating a namespace in azure. After fill all the required fields the button "create namespace" is disabled. Please help me.! Please see the image which describes my problem clearly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your #1 problem is that you're using the legacy Silverlight portal, from which all services have now been retired (aside from caching, which you're attempting to allocate). There's absolutely no reason you should be working via the Silverlight portal.

Go, instead, to [manage.windowsazure.com](https://manage.windowsazure.com). Here you'll find everything you need, *including* the cache service:

[image]

You can then create a cache with appropriate region and size:

[image]

Once it's created, it'll show up in your portal, under the Cache tab on the left.

[image]

Then, clicking through the cache name, you'll see several options, including the ability to scale:

[image]